# Invalid option value for attribute "size" in row

Tags: attributes, magento2.2.3

I am getting 2 below errors, please help me to sort out this issue

> 1. Value for 'size' attribute contains an incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in the row(s):
> 2. Invalid option value for attribute "size" in row(s):

i have mentioned size attributes in **"additional_attributes"** ,**"configurable_variations"** column. and same as in Back-end as well

I am attaching a screenshot for your reference

Thanks in advanced.
kk

Answer (score 0):

Please check line number: 2311 in csv where size attribute is missing and same you can find out for price attribute.after all value correct than import csv again.

Comment: Thanks Saniya, for the Reply by the way i am new and beginner to Magento it is a simple product, i checked in row there is 2311, in .csv file where size is mentioned in additional_attributes and price to without error, for your reference:  is any thing i am missing in other columns?where as 2310 row,brand=Under Armour,gender=UNISEX,pickfromstore=Tawar Mall,size=OSFA,upc=886450997110, in this it showing error, therefore both  are simple products. here is the sample file link http://corporate.sportscorner.qa/pub/static/frontend/Magento/sample.xlsx-